# How can I communicate with a Unix domain socket via the shell on Debian Squeeze?

Tags: shell, debian, socket, telnet

I’m running a Debian Squeeze web server. I’ve installed memcached on it, and configured memcached to listen on a Unix domain socket (at `/tmp/memcached.sock`), as it only needs to receive messages from the website, which lives on the same server.

It seems to be working fine, but I’d also like to communicate with memcached via the shell, to check that it’s doing what I think it’s doing.

memcached accepts messages via a simple ASCII protocol (if I understand correctly). If it was listening on TCP/IP, I could send messages to it via e.g. `nc`:

```
$ echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211
```

But I can’t figure out how to send that text to the domain socket instead.

On my laptop (which runs OS X Lion), both `nc` and `telnet` have options (`-U` and `-u` respectively) to use domain sockets. However, on my Debian Squeeze web server, these options aren’t present.

Comment: Not exactly answering this question, but also if you need a special format on your requests, e.g., using REST, you can use other tools such as `curl` instead to get it done for you automatically. E.g.: `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/images/json | jq`

Comment: @aderchox, I believe you meant HTTP(S). REST does not imply HTTP.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

With `netcat-openbsd`, there is a `-U` option. If you don't have it, you probably have `netcat-traditional` installed instead; I'd suggest switching.

Example command:
`nc -U /var/run/socket`

Comment: so netcat will create a new file at `/var/run/socket`? Is there a way to reuse an existing file?

Comment: @AlexanderMills If you tell it to listen (`-l`), it'll create the file. Otherwise, it expects the socket to already exist (and already have something listening on it). So the example command in the answer does not create the file.

Answer (score 142):

With [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat) (a 'bidirectional data relay between two data channels') you can connect to the unix domain socket like this:

```
$ socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/memcached.sock
```

Answer (score 36):

`netcat-openbsd` supports connecting to UNIX-domain sockets. Using this you can connect to either a *UNIX-domain stream socket* or a *UNIX-domain datagram socket*, and therefore you have to tell the socket's type to netcat.

for example, `/dev/log` file in Linux is a *UNIX-domain datagram socket* socket, thus `nc -U /dev/log` **won't work**. Instead use `nc -uU /dev/log`. Using -u along with -U tells netcat that it is a UNIX-domain datagram socket.

```
nc -U /tmp/socket  #Connect to UNIX-domain stream socket
nc -uU /tmp/socket #Connect to UNIX-domain datagram socket
```

Similarly, while using `socat`, use UNIX-CLIENT option. Using this option you can connect to both *UNIX-domain stream* and *UNIX-domain datagram* sockets. From its man page *(man socat)*, "*It  first  tries to connect and, if that fails, assumes it is a
              datagram socket, thus supporting both types*".

```
socat - UNIX-CLIENT:/dev/socket #connect to UNIX-domain socket, irrespective of its type
```

Comment: Excellent detail, regarding the distinction of socket types. Adding `-l` will create it, e.g. `sudo nc -luU /tmp/socket #create and listen to unix datagram socket`.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) on Debian.
To install it:

```
# apt-get install socat
```

Comment: That looks pretty good. I don’t appear to have `socat` installed on my server, but it’s certainly available: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/socat

Answer (score 17):

If you happen to be on a system that only has busybox installed, it may look like it doesn't support unix domain sockets (the `-U` option doesn't exist) but I found the following works:

```
$ echo "stats slabs" | nc local:/tmp/memcached.sock
STAT active_slabs 0
STAT total_malloced 0
END
```

This can be really helpful for creating health checks for alpine containers.

Comment: Could you add the required configuration options for this to work? Enabling `CONFIG_FEATURE_UNIX_LOCAL` is not sufficient. I also played with `CONFIG_NC_EXTRA` and `CONFIG_NC_110_COMPAT` but neither of that helped.

Comment: @yman I was just using a precompiled binary in an Alpine container. I think the config settings were https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/busybox/busyboxconfig or https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/busybox/busyboxconfig-extras

Comment: Seems both `NC_EXTRA` and `NC_110_COMPAT` config options need to be enabled, of course together with `CONFIG_FEATURE_UNIX_LOCAL`. Please consider extending the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Send the request "GET" to the socket "/tmp/server.sock" and print the result:

```
printf GET | socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/server.sock -
```