# Sending data to Unix socket failing unless proxied with socat via UDP

Tags: socat, unix-sockets, nc

I'm trying to debug why data isn't being sent over a Unix Domain Socket.

I have 2 applications which should be communicating over a UDS but aren't.

To test I've done the following:

Using `socat`, I listen on a socket like this:

`socat -x -u UNIX-RECV:/tmp/dd.sock STDOUT`

and using netcat to send data like this:

`echo "hello" | nc -U -w1 /tmp/dd.sock`

nothing happens.

But if I also set up socat as a proxy, to listen to a UDP port, and write that to the socket like this:

`socat -s -u UDP-RECV:9988 UNIX-SENDTO:/tmp/dd.sock`

Then sending via `netcat` to the UDP port works:

`echo "Hello" | nc -u localhost 9988`

I've also been able to get my client application to write UDP to the proxy and it's successful where is wasn't when writing to the unix socket.

I would like to understand why `socat` doesn't receive data written to it by `nc`, but does if I proxy over UDP.

Using Amazon Linux
4.14.101-75.76.amzn1.x86_64

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro . I mentioned the applications for background. My example which demonstrates the problem using `socat` and `nc` reproduces the problem. I shall update the question to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set up a listening *datagram* socket with `socat`+`UNIX-RECV:` and are attempting to talk to it via a *stream* socket with `nc`.

The second scenario works because in that case you added the missing `-u` flag to `nc`, so that both it and `socat` were employing a datagram socket.  It wasn't anything to do with there being a proxy.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294221/5132